# Combining python and JS (mapbox) for interactive rendering

Tags: python, web-mapping, mapbox

I plan on visualising a huge dataset (probably around 20-30GB of data) using Mapbox in order to have a very nice map visualization. However I would like this visualization to be interactive and I am pretty sure that both JS and my browser will not really like such an amount of data, so I wanted to have my data filtering/processing operations conducted with python and the rendering done dynamically with JS and Mapbox. I have seen that there is Python API for Mapbox, but all of the examples I have seen so far of it simply create a geojson dataset once and a html page, but it seems that the rendering code in JS is not dynamically generated. Would you guys know if there is any way to achieve that?

Comment: You could look at https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe to turn your dataset into Vector Tiles which enables the browser to handle large datasets.

Comment: @eczajk does that mean that I will have to upload my data online? I really can't do that, it might be sensitive data

Comment: You would need to use that tool to convert your GeoJSON to .mbtiles. Then you would need to serve the mbtiles to your application. You can do this by uploading mbtiles to MapBox or use another tile-server.

Comment: @eczajk the problem with that solution is that I don't have anything interactive working... It's basically a static rendering that is pre-processed... I would need something that people could filter through (show other dimensions, filter out some years, select only some parts of the data...)

Comment: @eczajk don't you think that something similar to this is possible? https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2015/07/08/us/census-race-map.html It is interactive and they do have a huge dataset too I suppose

Comment: The .mbtiles from tippacanoe are vector tiles. So you could conceivably create interactivity that would re-render styling based on some properties of the data (e.g. year). I'm not familiar with the NY Times map, but it is not truly interactive in the sense that you cannot filter by race/ethnicity - the map layer is static. The census tract hover interactivity appears to be driven by a parallel dataset.

Comment: @eczajk I checked the code and you are right. They actually also pre-rendered tiles... This solution totally makes sense, but that seems like a problem for me as I would like to be able to interact with the data (provide more information and so on...)